# How MS Word can automatically locate pictures?

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, latex, pictures

When you write a document in TeX

```
paragraph 1
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
paragraph 2
```

after compiling, you see that the final placement of the figure will not be necessarily between paragraph 1 and paragraph 2 and TeX, generously and genius-ly, finds the appropriate place for your picture.

But, in my MS Word 2013 x64 Win 7, I don't know what I should do to let MS Word finds the location of the pictures, intelligently?

Comment: I suppose that in Layout options, selecting the "fix position on page" option operates, similarly, by this difference that the position should be set by your selection, not by computer.

Comment: When you place the picture, is it in line with text, or do you have text wrap around it? (You can right-click on the picture and go to Wrap Text to see what's currently selected.)

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck Let's say it is inline; but, I think that doesn't matter because my question is about automatic locating system. Consider that I know about different Layout options and I never saw such intelligent locating system.

Comment: @hossayni If it's in line with text, then Word puts the picture in its own paragraph. So it will always be between paragraph 1 and paragraph 2, even if this leaves extra blank space on the page. That sounds like it's not what you want.  If you choose a different layout option, then right-click and go to Size and Position, you can adjust the layout.  None of those options are available if the Layout is set as in line with text.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck Though other options provide what inline layout doesn't have, they don't provide automatic locating.